# Transforming rectangle to disk-shape

Tags: calculus, algorithms

The problem is formed when I am doing image processing: transforming the left image to the right. I haven't found any proper method to transform the image directly, so an **algorithm** or **function** is needed to solve the problem.

In my opinion, transforming these two images can be defined as transforming a rectangle to a disk-shape (like part of CD-disk). Here, the radius of disk *R*, the distance from the inner circle to the outer circle, is equal to the corresponding length *R* of rectangle. Also, coordinates of each pixel of images are known. But I don't know which math tool or method can be employed.

I hope someone will tell me a proper **algorithm** to do the transforming, I will implement it in image-processing.

---

[image]

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://bridgesmathart.org/2012/cdrom/proceedings/118/paper_118.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Such transformation can be realized using the mapping like $f\colon\;\;z\mapsto e^z,\;\;\; z\in \mathbb{C},\;\;\;{\alpha}\leqslant\arg{z}<{\alpha}+2\pi,$ which can be written as
$$\pmatrix{x\\y}\mapsto \pmatrix{e^x \cos{y}\\e^x \sin{y}},\;\;\;{\alpha}\leqslant{y}<{\alpha}+2\pi.$$